# Logging to Adobe CQ5 using PuTTY

Tags: putty, aem

I would like to learn about connecting to the CQ5 server using Putty SSH/telnet client for windows to perform operations like server start/stop, check status etc

I tried connecting, but got connection refused.

If anyone could help with the steps to connect, it would be useful.

Thanks,
Sriram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The below is the Example that might be useful when you are using a putty client from windows, and the CQ5 is hosted in the Linux box.**

- open the putty window, provide the details

1)HostName or (Ip Address)

```
Example: 192.168.1.1
```

2) Enable SSH radio button(which defaults to port 22)

- then click on open which prompts you for the linux box username and
  password.
- Then navigate to the **bin** folder which is inside of your
  **crx-quickstart** folder is located.

> Example: Navigate to "/CQ5/Author/crx-quickstart/bin/"

- Use "**sh start**" or "**sh stop**" commands to run start and stop scripts of the CQ. [Some more info](http://dev.day.com/docs/v5_2/html-resources/cq5_guide_system_administrator/ch03s03.html)

> *You can list the process which are up and running on which address by " netstat -lnptu " command*
>
> *Use " kill -15 PID " for killing a process with specific process id (Example : kill -15 5574)*

Comment: Dev machines are in the Linux box, but the local server runs only in windows. Thanks VAr for the Very Useful info.

Answer (score 1):

This is not CQ5 related!
If the server you are trying to connect to is not offering ssh access you won't be able to connect this way. Maybe you are trying to connect to a windows-server? Try remote-desktop in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Felix provides a [shell](https://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-gogo.html) that allows you to interact with the OSGi framework and with shell extensions that CQ5 or applications that run on it can supply. Maybe that's what you're looking for.

Installing the `org.apache.felix.shell`, `org.apache.felix.shell.remote` and `org.apache.felix.shell.tui` bundles provides a remote shell that's accessible via `telnet 6666` by default.

Adding the `org.apache.felix.gogo.command`, `org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime` and 
`org.apache.felix.gogo.shell` bundles activates the richer [Gogo shell](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-gogo.html).